# Non-transparent font over transparent div

Tags: html, css

I cannot setup non-transparent font over transparent div.

[image]

I use this **CSS** for the `h3` but it does not work.

```
.posterTextContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: orange; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center; 
    display: block;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
}

    .posterTextContainer > h3 {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white !important;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)"!important;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100)!important;
        opacity: 1.0 !important;
        -moz-opacity: 1.0 !important;
        -khtml-opacity: 1.0 !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 0.4em 0.7em 0.5em 0.7em !important;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden !important;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="premieresList" class="owl-carousel owl-theme classPremieres" style="display:block; width:100%!important; height:auto!important;">
            @if (ViewBag.Premieres != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in (List<.FilmView>)ViewBag.Premieres)
                {
                    <div class="item" style="width:100%!important;">
                        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="@item.FileUrl" alt="" style="border: 1px solid hsla(30, 96%, 52%, 0.6);" />
                        <div class="posterTextContainer">
                            <h3>
                                 @item.Title.ToUpper()
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
```

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Post all of your code so we have a [mcve]

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have no another code that overrides the demonstrated one.

Comment: @Dimo - seems like you should. Where's your HTML? Where's the image?

Comment: This help? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeGEqe

Comment: @MichaelCoker Done

Comment: @MichaelCoker It works man! put it like the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is wrap your image and headline text in an element, and either float the element that wraps them or set it to inline-block so that it will conform to the shape of the image. Then set it to `position: relative`, set the headline to `position: absolute`, then use `rgba()` (with alpha transparency) as the background color for the headline.

```css
.posterTextContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  padding: 2px;
}

.posterTextContainer > h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="posterTextContainer">
  <img src="https://pmcvariety.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/inferno-movie-tom-hanks.jpg?w=1000&h=563&crop=1">
  <h3>text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `opacity:1.0` to something like `opacity:0.6`

Comment: Worked for me on a fiddle

Comment: Add the image as well then